# Rails 5 project without activerecord causing model generate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm facing a problem in a project using Rails 5.2 without ActiveRecord.

I've runned the command `rails new project --skip-active-record` and it's ok, but when I run a command to generate a model I get this error:

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:404:in
>   `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active
>   Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of
>   the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

I didn't understand why it ask about sqlite 3 in active record if I disabled it and I search over internet and don't find anyone talking about.

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ActiveRecord` then there's no need to generate a model using `rails g`.
You can just go to the `app/models` directory in your application and create a plain ruby class to work with it as a model.

Comment: So, If I want connect an external API using RestClient gem I need create my models manually, right? Because to create a model Rails by default necessity a database dependent?

Comment: I haven't used the `RestClient` gem on my own, but yeah you can always create a model on your own. Afterall its just a class. If its inheriting `AR::Base` it'll have a functionality to work with DB table as well.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
rails g model MODEL
```

will generate *model, migration and fixtures*. And this is related to **ORM**. So rails will look at database configuration. There you would have mentioned the ORM client as

```
adapter: sqlite3
```

You need to install **sqlite3 gem** for this. Add

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to your **Gemfile**

If you want to add just model alone create file inside `app/models` folder. But whats the point in doing this? Rails will look for the *table name* respect to the model's *class name* and throw an error

Comment: I'm using an external rest JSon API to data, so I need create my models manually, right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have an ORM. If that is the case then `running rails generate model` shouldn't do anything, it shouldn't even install sqlite by default. Try updating your sqlite gem

Answer (score 0):

The `$ bin/rails generate model ...` command actually creates a migration and an ActiveRecord model that's why you get the database-related error. See [Model Generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#model-generators).